# how to enable textbox under ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

[image]I have a functionality in which I take list of clients from user, first I store this list in the List Object in angularjs controller and then send it to the server. The problem is, When I take input from user, I have given some text boxes and after user fills up all the data, user clicks on ADD button next to the text boxes, Then the record just added gets appended to the blank row which is designed to take input. I have made a provision that the records are appended are "Read Only" or say "Disabled" and A UPDATE button next to it.
What I want is how do I write the code which will "Enable" a particular row whose update button is clicked. I have used angular js for it I am sharing some code snippet and one representative image for better understanding,
Please help..!!
Thank you
JSP page

```
<tbody id="insertionRow" ng-init="edit=true">
        <tr>    
            <th>#</th>
            <th class="required">Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone No</th>
            <th>Add</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="c in ctrl.client.clientOwnerVOList">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td class="col-lg-3"><input type="Text" class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="c.clientOwnerName"
            id="clientOwnerName{{$index + 1}}" data-ng-disabled="isDisable(c)" id="name">
        </td>

        <td class="col-lg-4"><input type="Email" class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="c.clientOwnerEmail"
            id="clientOwnerEmail{{$index + 1}}" data-ng-disabled="isDisable(c)"></td>

        <td class="col-lg-3"><input type="Text" class="form-control" 
            data-ng-model="c.clientOwnerPhone" data-ng-disabled="isDisable(c)"
            id="clientOwnerPhone{{$index + 1}}"></td>

        <td>
            <button id="add{{$index + 1}}" type="button"
                 data-ng-if="ctrl.client.clientOwnerVOList.indexOf(c)==0" data-ng-click="insert(c)"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
            </button>
            <button id="edit{{$index + 1}}" type="button"
                data-ng-if="ctrl.client.clientOwnerVOList.indexOf(c)>0"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
            </button >
            <button id="refresh{{$index + 1}}"  type="button" style="display:none"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i>
            </button>
        </td>

        <td><button type="button" data-ng-if="ctrl.client.clientOwnerVOList.indexOf(c)>0"
                ng-click="remove(c);" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg "></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" data-ng-if="ctrl.client.clientOwnerVOList.indexOf(c)==0"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg "></i>
            </button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Controller Code

```
$scope.insert=function(clientOwner){
    self.client.clientOwnerVOList.push({clientOwnerName:clientOwner.clientOwnerName,clientOwnerEmail:clientOwner.clientOwnerEmail,clientOwnerPhone:clientOwner.clientOwnerPhone});

                      clientOwner.clientOwnerName="";
                      clientOwner.clientOwnerEmail="";
                      clientOwner.clientOwnerPhone="";
    }

   $scope.isDisable = function(clientOwner){
              //alert("in new isDisable");
              if(self.client.clientOwnerVOList.indexOf(clientOwner)==0){
                  return false;
                }
              else{
                  return true;
              }

          }
```

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: Question is I have disabled the rows, now I want to enable row If I click the update button in front of it... How should I do that.. Please refer the image I have uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to the edit button in you html

```
    <button id="edit{{$index + 1}}" type="button"
        data-ng-if="ctrl.client.clientOwnerVOList.indexOf(c)>0"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-ng-click="editRow(c)">
        <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
    </button >
```

And something like this to your editable elements

```
<input type="Text" class="form-control" 
        data-ng-model="c.clientOwnerPhone" data-ng-disabled="!c.enable"
        id="clientOwnerPhone{{$index + 1}}">
```

And in controller

```
$scope.edit = function(row){

    row.enable = true;

}
```

And whenever updated data is submited make sure you pass the entire row as argument and in controller

```
//assuming the submit function to be like this

$scope.submit = function(row){
    row.enable = false;
}
```

Comment: This won't disable the others with `row.enable=true`. May or may not be expected behavior. Also requires cleanup to remove that property before sending object to server

Comment: You can always delete this key before sending to the server. Others will be disabled as it will be part of every object (row). I have tried this a lot of times in my projects and it works.

Comment: I have too... am pointing this out for OP. Disagree about *"others will be diabled"* as it will require looping array to set others false. it won't happen automatically

Comment: It wont require looping, as and when you submit a row you can set this key on every submission and since its a boolean you can change the value of it everytime to enable to disable depending on requirements

Comment: Sure... but only if it gets submitted. Otherwise can have numerous enabled rows. Just pointing out...not saying it won't work but also depends on OP expectations. Personally for user experience I think is better they can only have one active row at a time

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is have a variable `selectedItem` in controller. When you click edit you set the item `c` in your `ng-repeat` as the selected item.

Then in your `ng-if` and `ng-disabled` in view use comparison `c==ctrl.selectedItem`

Controller

```
self.selectedItem = data[0];
self.setSelected(item){
   self.selectedItem = item
}
```

View

```
<button edit ng-click="ctrl.setSelected(item)">
<input data-ng-model="c.clientOwnerName" data-ng-disabled="!c==ctrl.selectedItem">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good to use a variable(may be array/object) in `ng-disabled` condition as it is easy to toggle the variable. The array variable is used to map the edit condition of each row.

Suppose, I have an array items like below:

```
$scope.items = [{id: 101, name: 'item1'}, {id: 102, name: 'item2'}];
```

Template

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" >
    <td>
      <input type="text" ng-if="isEditItem[$index]" ng-model="item.id" />
      <span ng-if="!isEditItem[$index]">{{item.id}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" ng-if="isEditItem[$index]" ng-model="item.name"/>
      <span ng-if="!isEditItem[$index]">{{item.name}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-if="!isEditItem[$index]" ng-click="editItem($index)">Edit Item</button>
      <button ng-if="isEditItem[$index]" ng-click="saveItem($index)">Save Item</button> 
    </td>           
</tr>
```

In controller

```
$scope.isEditItem = [];

$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.unshift({});
    $scope.isEditItem[0] = true;
}

$scope.editItem = function($index) {
    $scope.isEditItem[$index] = true;
}

$scope.saveItem = function($index) {
    $scope.isEditItem[$index] = false;
}
```

So, in the above example, isEditItem array contains the edit condition of items. When user click edit button for a item, make true of the `index` in `isEditItem`. Make it false, when user click save button.

I just wanted you to give an example how it can be done. I think, you can update your code by looking this example.

[Plunker of the above example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2dABB8Ra5quFnTpcuxcD?p=preview)